# before a date in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

ONE Date is given for eg ( 11th May 2013 i.e Saturday). I have to find 7 business days(MON-FRI)  before this date. That is 3rd MAY 2013 i.e fri. I know how to find out the business days beteen two dates. by :-

```
SELECT from_date- todate - ((
          TRUNC (NEXT_DAY (from_date, 'SAT') - NEXT_DAY (todate - 1, 'SAT')) / 7) + (
          TRUNC (NEXT_DAY (from_date, 'SUN') - NEXT_DAY (todate - 1, 'SUN')) / 7)) + 1
FROM   dual;
```

But now i have just one given date and have to find the 7th day before this day (according to business days!)

Comment: Please define "business day".  Thanks.

Comment: Business days means mon-fri ......... have edited it

Comment: So Holidays appearing on a monday are considered to be business days.

Comment: @EvilTeach well in any other case you need to have a pre-defined holidays table, which existence wasn't mentioned by OP ;)

Comment: yep :)   Working on a holiday is nothing new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
 (
  SELECT (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)                      start_dt -- May 11 --
       , (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)-LEVEL                bus_days -- All bus days before May 11 --
       , to_char((trunc(SYSDATE)-2)-LEVEL, 'DY') wk_day
   FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (trunc(SYSDATE)-2)-((trunc(SYSDATE)-2) - 7) -- May 11-7 days ago=May 4
 )
WHERE wk_day NOT IN ('SAT', 'SUN')
ORDER BY bus_days
/

START_DT    BUS_DAYS    WK_DAY
--------------------------------
5/11/2013    5/6/2013    MON
5/11/2013    5/7/2013    TUE
5/11/2013    5/8/2013    WED
5/11/2013    5/9/2013    THU
5/11/2013    5/10/2013   FRI
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `sysdate` with whatever date you need.

```
02:35:58 SYSTEM@sandbox> ed
Wrote file S:\spool\sandbox\BUFFER_SYSTEM_36.sql

  1  select sysdate - 7 seven_days_ago, min(sysdate - level) seven_bdays_ago
  2    from dual
  3   where rownum <= 7
  4     and to_char(sysdate - level, 'DY') not in ('SAT', 'SUN')
  5* connect by level <= 11
02:36:16 SYSTEM@sandbox> /

SEVEN_DAYS_AGO      SEVEN_BDAYS_AGO
------------------- -------------------
04.05.2013 02:36:17 02.05.2013 02:36:17

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
```

Comment: Can't you `connect by level <= 9`? It removes a whole lot of recursive queries that aren't necessary...

Comment: @Ben that makes sense indeed. for some reason (probably the time being 2AM) I initially thought that rownum <= 7 would optimize them away in any case, but looking at execution plan statistics now proved me wrong...

Comment: what is level ? i am using PL/SQL and i dont know what level is for ? Can you help ?

Comment: @SonamKapoor level is a pseudocolumn in oracle sql that shows current row's depth in hierarchical query (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm). in this sample there's actually no hierarchy, usage of connect by level/rownum is a common trick to generate a data set out of nothing

Comment: ok... but cant i use simple PL/SQL for this.. because i am using sql developer to create a function

Comment: and my answer is not coming exactly correct... as i am not used to this kind of coding i am not getting the logic . Sorry if i said something wrong,just a beginner.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/10798/0

Comment: @Ben just figured out it should be 11 instead of 9; you can still encounter more than 2 weekends if you look 7 business days ago, for example if you start from monday

Comment: @SonamKapoor the logic is, generate a set of 11 days (assuming you get no more than 4 weekends while looking 7 business days back), filter all the weekends, and get the earliest remaining day

Comment: see there are two things i dont understand... one is the use of level.... what exactly is level.. and why is it used here and Connect by ..... because i have never used it in PL/SQL.

Comment: i am asking the usage so that i can convert the logic into my own code.

Comment: consider `connect by` a loop. something like `for level in 1 .. 11`

Comment: Ohkkk.. no i get it :) Thanx :)

Comment: @SonamKapoor keep in mind that connect by should be considered as a loop in this exact case, in general it is a very different thing. read the link I posted above

Comment: Nitpick: to_char(..,'DY') returns a locale specific string, so if you need to support different locales, you should also supply the NLS settings for to_char().

Comment: what is NLS settings ? :-o

Comment: NLS = national language support. It's a bunch of settings that configure things like date format, currency sign, decimal separator etc. Just google for "Oracle NLS"